# Monitor text that is highlighted

Tags: java, api, text, highlighting

This is more of a hypothetical question, I'm brainstorming some ideas for a project that I'm planning, and was curious if anyone knew of any APIs or methods of getting any highlighted text instantly on any window, for example from a browser or word processor. It could also have possibly a key command that would only read when pressed (Akin to CTRL+C adding the selected text to a clipboard)

Any knowledge in what APIs exist for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java is quite poor when it comes to monitoring activity in *other apps*. You'd need some native OS-level support for that.

Comment: I suspect you need to write a DLL which integrates with the windows GUI libraries, not in Java.

Comment: @Thilo Java is designed not grab data from other applications in ways which would be useful for hackers. ;)

Comment: Using JNA I imagine you could do that but that will be OS specific. I also imagine that you will need to constantly poll the window that has focus to get the text from it because I don't know if there is some kind of hook that will alert you whenever selection change in any application.

Comment: Ok it's not for a hacking tool ;) 

What about reading from the Clipboard would that work, that would I assume also allow multi-platform support?

Comment: I found a way of doing this through reading the clipboard.

[Reading pure text from clipboard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105778/java-get-pure-text-from-clipboard

Comment: Yes but the user need to copy himself the text into its clipboard, there is a way using JNA on Windows to easilyy get the currently selected text into the clipboard by emulating a `Ctrl-c`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use JNA to actually emulate a `Ctrl-C` (copy action) on the foreground window, and then read what is in the clipboard, after that you just need to restore what was in the clipboard.

This is a short sample:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class Foo implements ClipboardOwner {
    public interface CustomUser32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        CustomUser32 INSTANCE = (CustomUser32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", CustomUser32.class);
        HWND GetForegroundWindow();
        void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, int dwFlags, int dwExtraInfo);
    }

    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {
        // dummy: needed for `ClipboardOwner`
    }

    void controlC(CustomUser32 customUser32) {
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x11 /* VK_CONTROL*/, (byte) 0, 0, 0);
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x43 /* 'C' */, (byte) 0, 0, 0);
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x43 /* 'C' */, (byte) 0, 2 /* KEYEVENTF_KEYUP */, 0);
        customUser32.keybd_event((byte) 0x11 /* VK_CONTROL*/, (byte) 0, 2 /* KEYEVENTF_KEYUP */, 0);// 'Left Control Up
    }

    String getClipboardText() throws Exception {
        return (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    }

    void setClipboardText(String data) throws Exception {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(data), this);
    }

    String getSelectedText(User32 user32, CustomUser32 customUser32) throws Exception {
        HWND hwnd = customUser32.GetForegroundWindow();
        char[] windowText = new char[512];
        user32.GetWindowText(hwnd, windowText, 512);
        String windowTitle = Native.toString(windowText);
        System.out.println("Will take selected text from the following window: [" + windowTitle + "]");
        String before = getClipboardText();
        controlC(customUser32); // emulate Ctrl C
        Thread.sleep(100); // give it some time
        String text = getClipboardText();
        System.out.println("Currently in clipboard: " + text);
        // restore what was previously in the clipboard
        setClipboardText(before);
        return text;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Thread.sleep(2000); // take some time for you to select something anywhere
        System.out.println(foo.getSelectedText(User32.INSTANCE, CustomUser32.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

When you run it, you will have two seconds to select some text somewhere on any application, and then it will normally print it.

> Will take selected text from the following window: [java - Monitor text that is highlighted - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome]
>
> Currently in clipboard: I'm brainstorming some ideas for a project that I'm planning

You don't need to accept my answer, it was just to show you what I said in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getSelectedData() {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(2*1000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        Thread.sleep(2*1000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        Thread.sleep(2*1000);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        Thread.sleep(2*1000);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    String word = getSelectedData();
    return word;
}
```

private static String getDataFromClipboard() {

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
try {
    String result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    return result;
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("ERROR");
    return null;
}
}
```