# Copying text in Java without copy and paste or clipboard transfer

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am developing a 'text to speech' in Java. It is working well if the text to be converted into speach is copied into the JTextArea by  Drag and drop   or by  Clipboard transfer via cut/copy/paste. But I am seeking a method by which a text just selected  from any Browser, Text Editor or Excel Sheet etc. is copied to be set into my JTextArea. What should I do?

Comment: Define 'from anywhere' in such a way that it excludes drag and drop, and paste, but includes something else.

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839780/monitor-text-that-is-highlighted

Comment: 'anywhere' means : any browser (Opera, Internet explorer), word doc, notepad, excel etc.

Comment: why you want it without a clip board object?

Comment: Because the user required so. So I need a code or hint to write where copy and paste= selection.

Comment: Hi Smi Lee Thanks a lot for giving the link. It has provided me what I wanted.

Comment: It has provided you with a clipboard-based solution. You said that was that you didn't want, or what your client didn't want. Unfortunately that's the only choice there is. The discussion  seems a bit pointless.