# Copy selected text from other windows in Linux using Java

Tags: java, linux, clipboard

I am working on a dictionary project where I need to copy the selected word/text in any application's active window (e.g. a web browser) to the clipboard and then paste the clipboard contents to a JavaFX textfield.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855153/4963836) explains how to do this in Windows. The code uses the `user32` library and `HWND` property to detect the active window in the Windows OS, but in Linux, this example doesn't work.

Are similar libraries, and an example of using them, available in Linux?

Comment: I took the liberty of improving the question's wording/grammar and formatting to make the question clearer. Also added tags and improved title.

Comment: Thank you.
I'm sorry for my poor English grammar!