# Retrieving string from clipboard in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to get some text from the clipboard using this method, but it throws an exception into the string instead of the text.

Am I just doing it wrong or something?

```
Transferable t = cb.getContents(null);
String begin = t.toString();
System.out.println("Successfully fetched:");
System.out.println(begin);
```

Throws this error:

> sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable@6d03e736

Comment: Please include the declaration of the variable "begin"

Comment: See the accepted answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105778/java-get-pure-text-from-clipboard - you're missing a bit of code for getting the data out, and you're only getting the default Java `Object.toString()` instead.

Comment: `sun.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardTransferable@6d03e736` is not an error/exception, it is String representation of ClipboardTransferable object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code snippet which attempts to retrieve a `String` from the System clipboard:

```
String result = "";
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
boolean hasStringText = (contents != null) && contents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
if (hasStringText) {
    try {
        result = (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex); ex.printStackTrace();
}
```