# Java Swing to write to a text file from clipboard

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to learn Java Swing. I am trying to copy input data from UI to a clipboard and write it to a text file.

I have the below code to copy it to a clipboard and to create a text file. But I am facing difficulty in copying the data from clipboard to text file.

**Question: How do I pass argument to "Print Writer"?** I was trying to use "Queue" as I have copied to it earlier. Am I wrong?

```
private void hCopysaveButActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
   //JSpinner dateSpinner=hDateSpinner.get
   Date date=new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat ("E MM/dd/yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
   String rock= krock.getText();
   String get= "Date&Time: "+form.format(date)+"\n"+"\n"+krocklabl.getText()+krock;
   StringSelection Queue= new StringSelection(get);
   Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
   clipboard.setContents(Queue, Queue);
   
   
   try{
   Date datetime=new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat ("E_MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss_a_zzz");
   FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Driver\\"+form.format(date)+ ".txt");
       try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer)) {
           pw.println(+Queue);
           pw.close();
       }
  
   }    catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Handoff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Modified Code:

```
 try{
       String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); 
       Date datetime=new Date();
       SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat ("E_MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss_a_zzz");
       FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Driver\\"+form.format(date)+ ".txt");
           try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(writer)) {
               pw.println(data);
               pw.close();
           }
      
       }    catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Handoff.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }                                  

File gets created have input data like
```

> Date&Time: Wed 11/30/2016 at 08:16:16 PM ISTOvert # :User input not valid until its registered

But it should look like below.

> Date&Time: Wed 11/30/2016 at 08:16:16 PM IST
>
> Overt # : User input not valid until its registered

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get readable text only from clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105778/get-readable-text-only-from-clipboard)

Comment: And then, simply [use this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053467/how-do-i-save-a-string-to-a-text-file-using-java) to save it. You should try one thing at the time ;) first try to get the value of the clipboard, print it in the console. Only then, you can try to save it to a file.

Comment: @AxelH Thank you. I made a  couple of changes to my code. Now I am able to create a text file with inputs. But one concern is input text what is copied to the text file is not formatted its all in one line. I would like to add next line ("\n").

Comment: @AxelH Code added in try block `String data = (String) Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor); ` and passed argument as `pw.println(data);`

Comment: So, how do I append "\n" in the code so that input copied to file is user-friendly?

Comment: Update the code in your question with what you have, and off course, show an example of that input

Comment: @AxelH I have updated the question with modified code and output. Basically, I would need Date&time in one line and Overt in the next line.

Comment: This is your clipboard that is wrong ... I tried you code (by copying the code in the clipboard) and I have the file with the correct format, `\n` and everything like expected. Just print the data into the console ... this should be the same. So check what is copy in the beginning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129498/discussion-between-sady-and-axelh).

Comment: @AxelH First part of my code (Before try block) will copy it clipboard as expected with \n. I tested it by clicking on a button to copy the input and I paste it on text pad.
But, when I try to use the same to create a text file with input, that is when I get the input all in one line. Do you mean to say you have tested second part of the code (try block) and it worked for you, is that correct?

Comment: @AxelH I managed to pass `string get` to `pw.println`. But File that gets created is not getting formatted with `\n` input comes all in one line. However, the first part of my initial code that copy's input from UI is working fine with `\n`. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: @AxelH I used `System.lineSeparator()` instead of `\n` in the string and that solved the issue. Thanks for your help

Comment: I should have thought about it... you're welcome